# com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_NETWORK_NAME_DELETED exception

Tags: windows-server, smb

I am getting the following error stack trace, when I am trying to connect an SMB share that I connect using the library most of the time, so yes the code mostly works but sometimes not. I could not try anything yet because I do not have any idea about what can be wrong, the share config, the network or the code, no idea.

```
com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_NETWORK_NAME_DELETED (0xc00000c9): Authentication failed for 'your-user' using com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.NtlmAuthenticator@565d98da 
  com.hierynomus.smbj.connection.Connection.authenticate(Connection.java:182)
```

Here is my SmbConfig and I am using the `0.9.1` of smbj.

```
SmbConfig config = SmbConfig.builder()
                .withMultiProtocolNegotiate(true)
                .withSigningRequired(true)
                .withDfsEnabled(true)
                .build();
```

Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb/6ab6ca20-b404-41fd-b91a-2ed39e3762ea it gives more information about 0xC00000C9 - STATUS_NETWORK_NAME_DELETED exception and says

> The network name specified by the client has been deleted on the
>   server. This error is returned if the client specifies an incorrect
>   TID or the share on the server represented by the TID was deleted.

Should I think something happened to the share on the windows server during the execution of the code?

Comment: I have not encountered this before. From what I read this is environmental/on the server and typically not something the client can do anything about. You might want to talk to your network admin for this.

Comment: Thanks @HieryNomus it makes sense, I will investigate what was the issue during the time code ran (if we had any)

Comment: definitely there is something either in the share config or the network, I am having the same connection issues with my mac client

Comment: Well, that means it's at least not an SMBJ problem ;)